# ClosureFeedbackCellArray vs. FeedbackVector in V8

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

What is the difference between **ClosureFeedbackCellArray** and **FeedbackVector** in V8?

How to trigger the transition from **ClosureFeedbackCellArray** to **FeedbackVector**?

What done the *InterruptBudget* attribute in **FeedbackCell** means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between ClosureFeedbackCellArray and FeedbackVector in V8?

A `FeedbackVector` holds the type feedback for a function.

The function's `ClosureFeedbackCellArray` holds the FeedbackVectors for any closures created by that function (i.e. for nested functions).

> How to trigger the transition from ClosureFeedbackCellArray to FeedbackVector?

FeedbackVectors are allocated lazily, when a function has been executing for a bit.

> What does the InterruptBudget attribute in FeedbackCell mean?

The InterruptBudget is the remaining budget for unoptimized code execution of the given function until the next interrupt is triggered (which could potentially decide to kick off optimized compilation of that function).

Comment: ooo!! Got it! Thank you very much.

Comment: For the last two questions, I've done an experiment, finding that the `InterruptBudget`:
**1.** will be initialized as `BytecodeLength * 8`,
**2.** will be substracted by the length of the looped bytecode sequence until it is less than 0,  in the Return and Jump handlers, 
**3.** will be reset as `132 * 1024`, and repeat Step2. Once it is less than 0 again, the optimized compilation will be triggered.

From the aboves, I have two new questions:
**1.** why is **8**?  why is **132 * 1024**?
**2.** What's the relationship between `IC` and `FeedbackVector`?

Comment: Why FeedbackVector will be allocated lazily? It will consume more memory space? Or more time?

Comment: Allocating FeedbackVectors lazily saves memory, because some functions won't ever get one. ICs use FeedbackVectors to store data. The specific numbers are all heuristics that have been found to work well.

Comment: Thanks!!! Have another new **question**:  Is `InterruptBudget` the only condition that triggers optimization?

Comment: No; the InterruptBudget triggers interrupts. When an interrupt happens, optimization may or may not be triggered.